# Nova Launcher -Google problem

Tags: google, launcher, default-applications, nova-launcher

I have  a problem with [Nova Launcher](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.teslacoilsw.launcher). When I go to Google and press "`home`" , it always asks me to choose between launchers. This  happens only when I use Google, it's really annoying.

**Model:** Alcatel one touch pop c2
**OS:** Andorid 4.2.2 jellybean
**Nova Launcher version:** Nova Launcher Prime 4.2.2
**Root access:** yes
**Launchers:** Launcher, Nova Launcher

Here is video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ICJSZB0SEso

## Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: @beeshyams yes, nova launcher is already default launcher but when i start google and press "home" button it just asks me to choose between launchers, there is no any defaults for "Launcher".

Comment: [Default launcher resets every time i use the google now](http://forum.xda-developers.com/nexus-4/help/default-launcher-resets-time-google-t2531053) mentions a similar problem and using [Launcher Switcher](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=kr.mobilefirst.launcherswitcher) seems to have worked. Give it a try

Comment: @beeshyams thank you so much, i found one app acting like a launcher called "MMITest", i will remove that now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed, thanks to [XDA thread-Default launcher resets every time i use the google now](http://forum.xda-developers.com/nexus-4/help/default-launcher-resets-time-google-t2531053) pointed out [beeshyams](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/135255/nova-launcher-google-problem?noredirect=1#comment171063_135255).

As recommended in that thread, I installed an app called [Launcher Switcher](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=kr.mobilefirst.launcherswitcher) and I found one app acting like launcher (in addition to Nova and default launcher), in my case that was "MMITest", I just removed that app with [System app remover (ROOT)](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jumobile.manager.systemapp)

Comment: Edited, now please "accept" the answer to indicate a solution to others who have a similar problem in future

Comment: This would help you [What does it mean when an answer is "accepted"?](http://android.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer)